# Strange output and branch warning when compiling

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I compile a fortran 77 code using gfortran and get the following error:

10    open (23,file=outfile,status='old',access='append',err=10)
                                                                        1
Warning: Branch at (1) may result in an infinite loop

This happens several times.

One of the output files looks like the following:

^L6a10È      <90>  )  &<9b>LÓLÓLÕ<91><90>       <90>       <90>       È      <8e><9b>LÓLÓLÕ<93>2
  !MERCURY ¢¤õ/!ô<8a><8a><90>      ÿ<90>      ÿ<90>      ÿÌÖÏ©ü}M<91>
  "VENUS   «}>±{©±<8b><90>      ÿ<90>      ÿ<90>      ÿÊº93¿<8d>d<91>

However, it should just look like a table of text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your line of code

```
10 open (23,file=outfile,status='old',access='append',err=10)
```

specifies that the `open` statement should transfer control to itself (label 10) in case an error is encountered, so any error could trigger an infinite loop. It also suppresses the output of error messages. If you want to just check for an error status, I would suggest using the `iostat` and/or `iomsg` (Fortran 2003) arguments:

```
open (23, file=outfile, status='old', access='append', iostat=ios, iomsg=str)
```

Here `ios` is an integer that will be zero if no errors occur and nonzero otherwise, and `str` is a character variable that will record the corresponding error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `err=` argument in your `open` statement specifies a statement label to branch to should the `open` fail for some reason.  Your code specifies a branch to the line labelled `10` which happens to be the line containing the `open` statement.  This is probably not a good idea; a better idea would be to branch to a line which deals gracefully with an error from the `open` statement.

The warning from gfortran is spot on.

As to the apparent garbage in your output file, without sight of the code you use to write the garbage (or what you think are pearls perhaps) it's very difficult to diagnose and fix that problem.